# embedded TTF font works fine in Chrome, does not work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, truetype

I am working on a website based on a series of old video games called Quest for Glory, which involves using original fonts from the games. One such font is called gloryquest, and I notice it displays just fine on browsers such as Chrome, Brave and Opera but does not display on Firefox. Whenever I look at this site in Firefox, it only shows the fallback font.

Here is a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lWNO.jpg) to screenshots showing the difference.

The issue is evident on these pages:

https://bdferr.github.io/quest-for-glory1.html

https://bdferr.github.io/quest-for-glory4.html

https://bdferr.github.io/qfg-book.html

The font is a TTF which I have uploaded into a fonts folder in the same directory as the other website files on Github. Another font in the same folder, called Sierra-SCI-Menu-Font, displays with no problems, as seen here:

https://bdferr.github.io/quest-for-glory3.html

The only difference I can see between the two is that the one with the problem (gloryquest) has a fallback font, Pixelar Regular W01 Regular, which is linked to from a tag in the head like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fast.fonts.net/cssapi/35bb4fcb-e728-4a43-9ecf-79aafffd52cb.css"/>
```

Another TTF font called cardinal-regular has a similar problem. It always displays in Chrome and other browsers, but never in Firefox. It is specified in the relevant stylesheet like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: cardinal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("/fonts/cardinal-regular.ttf") format("ttf");
}
```

Gloryquest is specified in the relevant stylesheets like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: gloryquest;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("/fonts/gloryquest.ttf") format("ttf");
}
```

The one that always works is specified like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: SierraSCImenu;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("/fonts/Sierra-SCI-Menu-Font.ttf");
}
```

That is, I do not specify "format("ttf")" there, but if I leave that out for the other pages I get error messages like this:

Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8000/fonts/gloryquest.ttf

OTS parsing error: cmap: Failed to parse table

I do not get any error messages from Firefox. I do not see any problems using the fonts on my own machine, such as in Word.

Please advise!

Comment: I have looked at Quest for Glory on Edge/Chrome and on Firefox (all on Windows 10) and the typeface looks identical. What system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 too, 64 bit.

Comment: I am using Firefox version 90.0 and Chrome version 91.0.4472.164 if that helps.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://imgur.com/a/MDKwNR8) to screenshots for comparison.